# Cчитывание файла до определённого символа

Tags: java

Я считываю текстовый файл с помощью метода nextLine(), подскажите пожалуйста, как считать не целиком строчку, а строчку до определённого символа

Answer (score 0):

Нашла решение:

```
String stra = "Исходный фон <Название фрагмента>";
String resultStr = stra.substring(0,stra.indexOf('<'));
```